# Plotting histogram using ggplot2 for 2 numbers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create a plot from two values:

```
results<-data.frame(name=c("A","B"), values=c("0.8639503","0.7870299"))
qplot(name, data=results, geom="bar")
```

This gives me a plot, where the difference between the two bars is invisible. Can someone help how to create this plot so that the differences are visible?

Comment: can someone explain to me the point of re-editing the title with a typo?

Comment: @baptiste what you mean?

Comment: @PauloCardoso I don't know any Rome. With R, anything is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

```
ggplot(results, aes(x=name, y=values)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

will give you the desired result